# How to add logical operators for WFS in OpenLayers2?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

How I can add logical operators `AND`, `OR` both together for WFS in OpenLayers.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;    
    function init() {   
        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            2309872.5, 2399960.25,
            2388258.25, 2450114.75
            );
        var options = {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom()                                        
            ],
            maxExtent: bounds,
            maxResolution: 306.1943359375,
            projection: "EPSG:32644",
            units: 'm'
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
        var  map_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "cite:union - Tiled", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'cite:union',
                    tiled: true,
                    EPSG:32644,
                    tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true
                } 
            );      
        var layerPolygon2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Layer Information", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            visibility: true,
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.0.0",
            srsName: "EPSG:32644", // this is the default
            url:  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wfs",
            featureType:"union",
            featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
            extractAttributes: true,
            transparent:true,
            geometryName: "the_geom"
        })
        filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
            filters: [
            new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
               type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
               filters: [
                   new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                      type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                      property: "classes",
                      value: "A?Pt"
                   }),
                   new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                      type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                      property: "classes",
                      value: "P"
                   })
               ]
            )}
            new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
                filters: [
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                       type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                       property: "luse_2005",
                       value: "BU"
                    }),
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "luse_2005",
                        value: "CL"
                    })
                ]
            )}  
        ]   
    })                             
});
map.addLayers([map_wms,layerPolygon2]);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
<div id="map" style="border:1px solid black;width:900px; height:700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run above code in browser nothing is being displayed and Firebug is showing an `ReferenceError: init is not defined init() error`.

Comment: problem solved..we can use both operators AND,OR togehter in WFS openlayers.

Comment: This doesn't have much detail. Can you show a code sample, explain any issues you've found (e.g. with WFS server support), and anything else that may help other users.

Answer (score 2):

BradHards...I have just define a rule outside the vector layer and use this in vector as we do to give style for vector layers.

```
var rule_fsa = new OpenLayers.Rule({
            filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
            filters: [
                new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
                filters: [
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "classes",
                    value: "A?Pt"
                    }),
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "classes",
                    value: "P"
                    })
                    ]
                    }),
                    new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
                    filters: [
                        new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "luse_2005",
                        value: "BU"
                        }),
                        new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                        property: "luse_2005",
                        value: "CL"
                        })
                        ]
                        })

                ]
                }),
                symbolizer: {
                fillColor: "#ff00ff",
                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                strokeWidth: 0,
                }
                });



            style.addRules([rule_fsa]);
```